# Understanding zookeeper status command's result

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am firing the below command as per the zookeeper admin documentation.

```
echo status | nc localhost 2181
Zookeeper version: 3.4.5-cdh6.2.0--1, built on 06/14/2018 06:15 GMT
Clients:
 /12.44.3.230:55192[1](queued=0,recved=156255,sent=156255)
 /12.44.3.230:44016[1](queued=0,recved=562591,sent=565466)
 /12.44.3.228:46362[1](queued=0,recved=349229,sent=349305)
 /12.44.3.222:39046[1](queued=0,recved=1388139,sent=1396205)
 /12.44.3.224:54920[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)
 /12.44.3.223:43736[1](queued=0,recved=331554,sent=331558)
 /12.44.3.226:54258[1](queued=0,recved=331558,sent=331562)

Latency min/avg/max: 0/2/6421
Received: 97238098
Sent: 97583872
Connections: 7
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0xd006499c1
Mode: follower
Node count: 3157`
```

I want to know the active connections to zookeeper server. Here in this case is is 7 ? If yes , what does the [1] and [0] after the ip address indicate

Thanks

Tried : echo status | nc localhost 2181

Need to know how can understand the result of this command